# Sphinxcontrib.bibtex problems when making latexpdf document

Tags: python, python-sphinx, bibtex

I am using `Sphinx` (version 1.1.3) & `sphinxcontrib.bibtex` to create a document for a python coding project I am doing.

I have the following in a separate file from the rest of my documents in a file named *zreferences.rst*

```
.. rubric:: References

.. bibliography:: refs.bib
   :cited:
```

This works fine when building a html output with `make html`; however, when I run `make latexpdf`, the references are absent from this page of the document, but they do show on the *Bibliography* page that is automatically created from the latex template Sphinx uses.

I don't want to have a redundant references page, so I tried removing the references document, but then the html build ceases to compile.

Is there anybody familiar with Sphinx, LaTeX and Bibtex that knows what's going on here? Thanks!

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: I developed a work around, which I didn't count as enough of a solution to put it here. I just put the `.. bibliography:: refs.bib` bit on the index page, which is not included in the `LaTeX` build; though, I see that I am getting an empty page with "Content:" at the top, so not sure that is working either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sphinx's latex writer needs fixing to match the html output more closely. This issue will occur also if you use regular citations in Sphinx: it has nothing to do with sphinxcontrib-bibtex per se.

Users of sphinxcontrib-bibtex are of course the most likely ones to encounter this problem. I've created an upstream ticket for it: https://github.com/mcmtroffaes/sphinxcontrib-bibtex/issues/48

For now, a workaround for this issue is to create a rubric only when html is generated:

```
.. only:: html

  .. rubric:: References

.. bibliography:: refs.bib
```

Comment: Thank you Matthias. I suppose I will leave this open in the event a solution develops.

Comment: I've researched this a little bit more and stumbled on the "only" directive: http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/misc.html#including-content-based-on-tags Have you tried it?

Comment: Heh, it works. :-) I've edited my answer accordingly.